# What are PNG~ files?

Tags: png, file-format, file-management

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I keep getting files with the `~` symbol beside them.
I have the actual PNG version of an image but right under is the same file, labeled `PNG~`.
Should I keep them? Is it safe to delete them?
Looks like this (happens with krita files as well):

[image: krita file with ~ symbol]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prefixed or suffixed tildes usually represent temporary files or backups.  Sometimes they may persist longer than they're meant to, which usually means your software didn't finish a save operation or something similar.

If you have the actual PNG and KRA files intact, it should be safe to delete the temporary/backup files.  If you want to see their contents to make sure, just remove the tilde and open them.

Comment: To add a little: KRA files are Krita files

Comment: Many programs put the ~ at the _beginning_ of the filename, like ~$lename.ext for Microsoft Office applications on Windows.